# Issue with Scrolling in Android Native app using Appium

Tags: java, android, scroll, appium

For my Native Android App , I have been trying for the past 2 weeks to get appium to scroll down on my native app. I have tried  `driver.scrollTo("Accounts");`
Then I got this error

```
[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: CATCH_ALL: io.selendroid.server.common.exceptions.SelendroidException: method (by) not found: -android uiautomator
```

and many other examples that I have found. Nothing seems to work . This is the latest example that I have tried .

Using appium 1.5.2 and appium java client  version: ‘3.3.0'. When I try to run the following code.

```
    TouchAction tAction=new TouchAction(driver);
    int startx = driver.findElement(By.id("line_chart_line_chart")).getLocation().getX();
    int starty = driver.findElement(By.id("line_chart_line_chart")).getLocation().getY();
    int endx = driver.findElement(By.id("actionBarLogo")).getLocation().getX();
    int endy = driver.findElement(By.id("actionBarLogo")).getLocation().getY();
    System.out.println(startx + " ::::::: " + starty + " ::::::: " + endx +  " ::::::: " +  endy);
    //  This is what the console printed out  startX=560 ::::::: starty=1420 ::::::: endx=560 ::::::: endy=240  
    //First tap on the screen and swipe up using moveTo function
    tAction.press(startx,starty).moveTo(endx,endy).release().perform();
```

Then I get this error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy 
error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 27 milliseconds
```

I am at a loss on what to do. In order to click on an element it has to be visible on the screen . In order for this element to appear on the screen I need to scroll down to it.

Is there something that I am doing wrong??? I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used Selendroid mode, which does not support UiAutomator By method.
You can change your appium running mode to UiAutomator by setting desired capability `automationName` to `Appium`

Answer (score 0):

This function does the trick for me, put in "Accounts" for elementName when calling it in your case.

```
public static void scrollToElementAndroid(AndroidDriver driver, String elementName, boolean scrollDown) {
    String listID = ((RemoteWebElement) driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView)")).getId();
    String direction;
    if (scrollDown) {
        direction = "down";
    } else {
        direction = "up";
    }
    HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
    scrollObject.put("direction", direction);
    scrollObject.put("element", listID);
    scrollObject.put("text", elementName);
    driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code . I tried what you said but got the following error _org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds_   Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to run other scripts on your device or does it crash at where you call the function? There might be another solution, although you might have to play around a bit to have it scroll to where your element is shown, you can try driver.swipe(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, duration).

Comment: When I ran the following code ***driver.findElement(By.id("login_username")).sendKeys(“UserID");
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 MobileConfig.driver.findElement(By.id(“User_Password")).sendKeys(“Password”);
 thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.findElement(By.id("login_button")).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.swipe(560, 1420, 560, 240, 2000);***     Every line of the code execute successfully except the driver.swipe line. I get this error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:Origin An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.Could not proxy. Proxy error: cont in next commen

Comment: So thingking maybe it is the driver. I am using ***driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://appium_IP_goes_Here:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);*** Is that the same way you are getting the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Use code like below:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int x = size.width / 2;
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.75);
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 1000);
```

Comment: The ***Driver.swipe command is what I am having and issue with.*** Any time I try to run that command in my code I get This error An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - undefined (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
      Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds"